# Cannot assign to 'parameters' in 'self' error - from CS193p Stanford Online Course

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cs193p

I am currently working on the Smashtag application which can be downloaded here: http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/

I have been following along with the iTunes U video (YouTube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIwaIEfPAh8&spfreload=10 ) and I can't get past the errors I have been getting.

Even after downloading the final copy of the app from the Stanford website I am seeing these Swift Compiler Errors still popping up.

It continues to say Cannot assign to 'parameters' in 'self'

Could this be from Xcode being updated to 6.3 after this Smashtag app learning course was released in February/March 2015?

I appreciate your help, not sure how to solve this at the moment.

```
private var twitterAccount: ACAccount?

public class TwitterRequest
{
    public let requestType: String
    public let parameters = Dictionary<String, String>()

    // designated initializer
    public init(_ requestType: String, _ parameters: Dictionary<String, String> = [:]) {
        self.requestType = requestType
        **self.parameters = parameters**
    }

    // convenience initializer for creating a TwitterRequest that is a search for Tweets
    public convenience init(search: String, count: Int = 0, _ resultType: SearchResultType = .Mixed, _ region: CLCircularRegion? = nil) {
        var parameters = [TwitterKey.Query : search]
        if count > 0 {
            parameters[TwitterKey.Count] = "\(count)"
        }
        switch resultType {
            case .Recent: parameters[TwitterKey.ResultType] = TwitterKey.ResultTypeRecent
            case .Popular: parameters[TwitterKey.ResultType] = TwitterKey.ResultTypePopular
            default: break
        }
        if let geocode = region {
            parameters[TwitterKey.Geocode] = "\(geocode.center.latitude),\(geocode.center.longitude),\(geocode.radius/1000.0)km"
        }
        self.init(TwitterKey.SearchForTweets, parameters)
    }

    public enum SearchResultType {
        case Mixed
        case Recent
        case Popular
    }
```

Comment: parameters seem to be  `let`. Make it `var`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Swift 1.2, giving your constant variables an initial value (not in `init`) means they cannot be reassigned a value in `init`. Therefore, because you're setting an initial value of `parameters` to be an empty dictionary, you cannot give `parameters` a new value in `init`. To solve this change your code to:

```
public class TwitterRequest {
    public let requestType: String

    // Note - now we just define the type here. 
    public let parameters: Dictionary<String, String>

    public init(_ requestType: String, _ parameters: Dictionary<String, String> = [:]) {
        self.requestType = requestType
        self.parameters = parameters
    }

    // Other stuff
}
```

Alternatively you could change `parameters` to be a `var`, as pointed out by @Thomas Kilian in his comment. However, if you're not going to change the values stored in `parameters` it makes more sense to declare it as `let` and use the code above.